# ngAudio not loading in controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

Using ngAudio, I cannot seem to get my code to work when I load an ngAudioObject within the controller. I am able to use the directives to work with my wav file directly in the view (so I know I have linked everything correctly) but not in the controller. I'm working with a number of modules and wondering if there is a conflict...

Please let me know if there is something obviously wrong.

```
var myApp = angular.module('screenApp', ['firebase','ngAudio']);

myApp.controller('screenController', ['$scope','$http','$firebaseArray','$interval', function($scope,$http,$firebaseArray,$interval,ngAudio) {

    $scope.audio = ngAudio.load('sounds/dingding.wav');

...
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation

> When using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.

Your parameters and annotation array are out of sync. Add `'ngAudio'` to the annotation array.

```
myApp.controller('screenController', ['$scope','$http','$firebaseArray','$interval', 'ngAudio', function($scope,$http,$firebaseArray,$interval,ngAudio) {

    $scope.audio = ngAudio.load('sounds/dingding.wav');
```